# mono custom DLL load

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am using mono to build a c# on OS x 10.8

I get an exception:
Instance    {System.DllNotFoundException: libiodbc.dylib   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.Odbc.libodbc:SQLAllocHandle (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandleType,intptr,intptr&)   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open () [0x00000] in :0 } System.DllNotFoundException

The libiodbc.dylib is located in /usr/lib.

I referred to mono documentation (http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Library_Names) . Here is what I have tried:

I have set my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to include /usr/lib

I have set my DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH to include /usr/lib

I have included the config line in my too:

```
    <configuration>
       <dllmap dll="libiodbc" target="libiodbc.dylib" />
    </configuration>
```

My last option is .config file. I do not know whether to drop this .config file on OS X. Please help. I am stuck on this for days

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see where your application is actually looking for the file, you can do this by setting the MONO_LOG_LEVEL environment variable like this:

```
export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug; mono YourApp.exe
```